# How to connect to LDAP with NTLM in Node.js

Tags: python, node.js, ldap, ntlm, express-ntlm

I'm building an app where employees should be able to login with their LDAP credentials through a web form.

I have a problem converting this working Python function, that uses `ldap3` library, into Node:

```
def authenticate_ldap(
        username: str,
        password: str
        ) -> dict[str, str, str]:
    try:
        conn = Connection(
            server='ldapDomain', user=username,
            password=password, authentication=NTLM,
            auto_bind=True
        )
        conn.search(
            'DC=smth,DC=com', f'(sAMAccountName={username})',
            attributes=['department', 'displayName', 'description']
        )
        name = conn.entries[0].displayName
        filial = conn.entries[0].department
        pos = conn.entries[0].description

    except LDAPBindError:
        return False
    data_user = {
        'name': str(name),
        'department': str(filial),
        'position': str(pos)
        }
    return data_user
```

Unfortunately, noone is familiar with Node in my company and I've been searching and trying for some time without any luck.

I've tried using [windows authentication strategy](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-windowsauth/) for `Passport.js` (non-integrated one), but not sure how to pass username and password to the function and when I hardcode them, it still throws `52e` error (even with a wrong username).

**Update:**
I was able to connect via Postman using `express-ntlm` library and had no luck to do the same through a browser form. Tried to send an auth header ('NTLM ' + 'base64encoded credentials'), but it returns 'Not a valid NTLM message:' error.

And just to add some more info: I've played around with the python function and it is necessary to use NTLM, simple bind doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like Python, you should remove the Node.js tag. +Stay clear of NTLM, use SIMPLE bind. A little less secure (because the server gets to see the password) but a lot easier to set up.

Answer (score 1):

You probably fail the first bind and it goes downhill from there.

I don't know Node much either, but I know a thing or two about LDAP. Here is how you usually go about it.

First, you need in your configuration (along with the hostname of the LDAP server):

1. The distinguished name of a service account for your application. It should look something like this `cn=myapp,ou=users,dc=smth,dc=com`
2. A password for your service account

With that in hand, when you receive a username password combination to validate, you go through the following:

1. Connect to the LDAP server with your service account, using [`SIMPLE` bind](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind.html?highlight=auto_bind#simple-bind), not NTLM
2. Search for the user to get their distinguished name (aka `dn`)
3. Bind again with the `dn` of the user and the password you received.

I don't have anything to test, but the code should look like this:

```
def authenticate_ldap(
        username: str,
        password: str
        ) -> dict[str, str, str]:
    try:
        conn = Connection(
            server='ldapDomain', user=config.app_username,
            password=config.app_password
        )
        conn.search(
            'DC=smth,DC=com', f'(sAMAccountName={username})',
            attributes=['department', 'displayName', 'description']
        )

        user_dn = conn.entries[0].entry_dn 

        conn.unbind() #YMMV, but I prefer to unbind the app

    except LDAPBindError:
        # Save yourself a lot of blind debugging with two try statements
        print("The application cannot connect or something")
        return False

    try:        
        conn = Connection(
            server='ldapDomain', user=user_dn,
            password=password
        )

        # Validate the user's password
        name = conn.entries[0].displayName
        filial = conn.entries[0].department
        pos = conn.entries[0].description

    except LDAPBindError:
        print("The application cannot validate the password somehow")
        return False

    return {
        'name': str(name),
        'department': str(filial),
        'position': str(pos)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Python function is working fine, but I need to implement the same logic in Node.